# Android Quiz Fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments

Making a complicated quiz/survey in Android. From what I understand I should have a Quiz activity and use fragments for each question, dynamically populating the questions/answers as needed. This survey uses radio buttons, check boxes, text input, etc.

Do I need to create a fragment for each type of question? (e.g. one for radio buttons, another for text input).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should make a new fragment for each type of question and reuse.
You should have a Question Object (holds a question which you would pass to each fragment).

Comment: Thanks. I didn't include in my question, but do you know how I could handle irrelevant question skipping? For instance, if the user answers 'no' then skip the next question.

Comment: You should have an array of question objects and iterate through each question and display each according question fragment. If you want to skip to the next question you can just increment the array index for that question to present the next question.